# How to break out of function update()?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to break out of my `update()` function. Here is what I've tried:

```
if (score.l1 > 20) {
  break;
}
```

but it just returns "Illegal break statement"

Answer (score 0):

`break` only works inside a loop. What you can do is `return;` instead.

```js
if (score.l1 > 20) {
    return;
}
```

Comment: All of the basic questions about JavaScript have been asked and answered. Better to mark something as a duplicate than to post yet another answer.